# Default Input is empty when Github Action crop is execute

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to get default value when github action execute by cron job. but it picking empty instead of default value.

Note getting why its not picking default value. Any idea?

Here is my code

```
workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      typeOfTesting:
        type: choice
        description: Select Type of Test
        default: "stage-test"
        required: true
        options:
          - stage-test-local-All
          - stage-test
          - stage-test-Uptime

  schedule:
    - cron: "0 1 * * *"
    - cron: "0 11 * * *"

jobs:
  WebdriverIO-Automation:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Selection of Testing type
        run: |
          echo "Branch Name: ${{ github.event.inputs.typeOfTesting }}"
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`inputs` is not available to cron triggers. They are available to workflows triggered by the workflow_dispatch event only.

If you want to default value for corn you need to handle it in a step like:

```yaml
workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      typeOfTesting:
        type: choice
        description: Select Type of Test
        default: "stage-test"
        required: true
        options:
          - stage-test-local-All
          - stage-test
          - stage-test-Uptime

  schedule:
    - cron: "0 1 * * *"
    - cron: "0 11 * * *"

jobs:
  WebdriverIO-Automation:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Selection of Testing type
        run: |
          echo "Branch Name: ${{ github.event.inputs.typeOfTesting == '' && github.event.inputs.typeOfTesting  || 'stage-test' }}"
```

Please take look [here](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/409#issuecomment-752775072) for a fake ternary expression:

```yaml
steps:
      - name: stuff
        env:
          PR_NUMBER_OR_MASTER: ${{ github.event.number == 0 && 'master' ||  format('pr-{0}', github.event.number)  }}
```

Comment: So, 'stage-test' is considered default if ```github.event.inputs.typeOfTesting``` is empty right? @Krzysztof Madej

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Actually, I want to use in if condition, 
` - name: Test
        run: |
          if [ ${{ github.event.inputs.typeOfTesting == '' && github.event.inputs.typeOfTesting || 'stage-test-Uptime' }} ]; then
            echo "action_state=YYY" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          else 
            echo "action_state=XXX" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi
            npm run ${{ github.event.inputs.typeOfTesting }}` but it does not run else part.